# Permissions for Bitnami / EC2 WordPress plugins

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, permissions, bitnami

I keep having problems with permissions on Bitnami Wordpress. I'm wondering if there's a correct way of doing things in relation to file and folder permissions. The default owner is bitnami:daemon. I've set the permissions to 755 for folders and 644 for files. The problem arises when a plugin needs to do something with the files, such as regenerating thumbnails (this is another problem in itself). 
The plugin did regenerate the thumbnails, but there are a lot of errors in the log, most likely because it was trying to delete the old thumbnails and was denied permission. The new files have daemon:daemon ownership. This means that some files are owned by bitnami, and others are owned by daemon. Is there a way to avoid these errors?

For one plugin I gave it daemon:daemon ownership to allow it to work in its own folder, but I'm not sure if I should do that for all media files or not.
Also when I upload a file, I set the permissions on each file/folder manually. I'm also wondering if there's a way to have the permissions correctly without doing this manually every time a file is uploaded.

Comment: Please give permission also 755 to files too

Comment: Hi Bitnami Engineer here. We set the permissions to be 664 and 775 inside the installation folder of WordPress. The owners are bitnami:daemon because either the user using the command line and the Apache service (daemon) needs write permissions inside that folder.  In our troubleshoot section, we explain how to modify the permissions of the wp-content folder https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#troubleshooting-wordpress `sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content` and `sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the permissions, and it's all working without errors now. I was able to upload directly in the directory.

Comment: this helped me with putty and WinSCP, but fyi, it does not update permissions through wordpress editor.